# Get sum of all div's width on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the sum of all div's width on the page and show it on click in alert

The problem I'm facing is when I click on the button again to show the sum the result return double and if I click again for the third time, result return tripled and so on

My code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/enypx/

HTML

```
<button>Size of all divs?</button><br>
<div style="width: 100px;">REMOVE</div>
<div style="width: 150px;">REMOVE</div>
<div style="width: 200px;">REMOVE</div>
<div style="width: 150px;">REMOVE</div>
<div style="width: 100px;">REMOVE</div>
```

jQuery

```
var divs = 0;
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').each(function () {
        divs += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    alert(divs + 'px');
});

$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the click handler you need to reset the value of `divs` variable... also it can be a local variable

In your case the `divs` is a global variable whose initial value is `0`, when you click the button first time it is updated to value `x` - now the value of the shared variable is `x`. Now when you click the button again instead of starting with the value `0` the variable value is started from `x`.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var divs = 0;
    $('div').each(function () {
        divs += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    alert(divs + 'px');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jcNUy/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your variable storing the widths (`divs`) long outlives the particular function call. Move the variable `divs` inside the click function, like this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var divs = 0;
    $('div').each(function () {
        divs += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    alert(divs + 'px');
});

$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Moving the variable inside the function limits the time the variable is living to the time the function is executing. Keep in mind that you won't have access to this variable *outside* of this function then.

Answer (score 0):

Reset `var divs` to `0` before closing the click function.

```
var divs = 0;
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').each(function () {
        divs += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    alert(divs + 'px');
    divs = 0;     // NOTE: reset divs. Value retains with every
                  // click otherwise.
});

$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

U have to set the `var divs=0;` on every button click

```
var divs;
$('button').click(function () {
    divs=0;
    $('div').each(function () {
        divs += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    alert(divs + 'px');
});

$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/enypx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

using outerWidth that provides extra padding etc

```
  $(selector).outerWidth(true) ;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/harpreet0103/2b3sN/)

you can use width() for the div widths u provided

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/harpreet0103/2b3sN/1/)